# Error in retrieving data from Cassandra using Apache Spark Connector in java

Tags: java, cassandra, apache-spark

I have problem for retrieving data from Cassandra table using sparkCassandraConnector. I created a name space called "ks" and table "student" in Cassandra. the table is like follow:

id | name

----+-----------

10 | Catherine

I started Spark locally with running start-all.sh

Then I created this the class "SparkCassandraConnector" which has a command for connecting spark and Cassandra.What I am trying to do is to retrieve data from student table and print it on screen.

The error I get is "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: SparkCassandraConnector$Student
        java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
        java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
        java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:340)

This is my Program:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;

import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;

import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;

import java.io.Serializable;

import static com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraJavaUtil.javaFunctions;

public class SparkCassandraConnector  implements Serializable {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application");

    conf.setMaster("spark://127.0.0.1:7077");
    conf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1");
    String[] jars = new String[10];
    jars[0] = "~/.m2/repository/com/datastax/spark/spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.10/1.1.0-alpha4/spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.10-1.1.0-alpha4.jar";
    jars[1] = "~/.m2/repository/com/datastax/cassandra/cassandra-driver-core/2.1.0/cassandra-driver-core-2.1.0.jar";
    jars[3] = "~/.m2/repository/com/datastax/spark/spark-cassandra-connector_2.10/1.1.0-alpha4/spark-cassandra-connector_2.10-1.1.0-alpha4.jar";
    jars[4] = "~/.m2/repository/com/datastax/cassandra/cassandra-driver-core/2.1.0/cassandra-driver-core-2.1.0.jar";
    jars[5] = "~/.m2/repository/org/apache/cassandra/cassandra-thrift/2.1.0/cassandra-thrift-2.1.0.jar";
    jars[6] = "~/.m2/repository/org/apache/cassandra/cassandra-clientutil/2.1.0/cassandra-clientutil-2.1.0.jar";
    conf = conf.setJars(jars);
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

    JavaRDD<String> rdd = javaFunctions(sc).cassandraTable("ks", "student", Student.class)
            .map(new org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function<Student, String>() {
                @Override
                public String call(Student person) throws Exception {
                    return person.toString();
                }
            });
    System.out.println("Data as Person beans: \n" + StringUtils.join(rdd.collect(), "\n"));
}
public static class Student implements  Serializable{

    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    public Student(){

    }
    public Student(Integer id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

}

this is my POM file:

```
<dependencies>


    <!--Spark-->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0-alpha4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0-alpha4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-catalyst_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: I suggest you to go forward with assembly plugin, you can read motivation for it and example with sbt here: http://eugenezhulenev.com/blog/2014/10/18/run-tests-in-standalone-spark-cluster/

Comment: Thank you for the link. but do you agree that I provided necessary jar files and I shouldn't get that error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the provided jars, the jar containing the job, and hence the `Student.class` is missing. A quick fix it to add the jar that's in your project's `./target` folder.

An alternative is to package your job and all dependencies in an 'uber jar' and use that uber jar as only declared jar. Look into the [maven shade plugin.](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/)

Jars can also be provided from the command line using `spark-submit --jars` option.

Comment: I tried to add jar of the main class(first suggested solution), but it doesn't work.  then I tried to use spark-submit --jars but I got error of unrecognized -jar option. the I tried created Uber jar and this solution works. Thanks to @maasg